# force button enable change before function finish

Tags: multithreading, qt, qml

I have a qml image button. If button is pressed then an long operation is start at C++ side. I want button is disable when click on it , them enable it after function is finish.

```
Image {
    id:searchimgbtn
    source: "/Images/Search.png"
    height: parent.height
    width: dp(32)
     fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
     enabled: isvalF
     opacity: isvalF ? 1 :0.1

     MouseArea {
         anchors.fill: parent
         hoverEnabled: true

         onClicked: {

            disablesearchbutton();
             getcbsvalue();


         }

         onPressed:{
             searchimgbtn.scale=1.08
      //       searchimgbtn.opacity=0.3
       //      opacity: enabled ? 1 :0.1
         }
         onReleased: {
             searchimgbtn.scale=1
       //      searchimgbtn.opacity=1
       //      opacity: enabled ? 1 :0.1

         }


     }
}
```

Comment: how are you changing the value of isvalF ?

Comment: int disablesearchbutton metod

Comment: Are you using a send signal to indicate the end of c++ operation, and change value of isValF upon receiving signal?

Comment: @nayab , that is true . Signal is triggered end of c++ , than qml slot catch. IsValF is true again

Answer (score 0):

You need to branch your long running job into another process/thread, so that the UI-Process is not blocked and can render.
Look into [QProcess](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprocess.html) or [QThread](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qthread.html), I'm using it to ping stuff.

```cpp
    const QString PING_PATH = "C:/Windows/System32/ping.exe";
    QStringList pingArguments << "192.168.1.1";

    QProcess *pingProcess = new QProcess(this);
    pingProcess->startDetached(PING_PATH, pingArguments);
```

Comment: I have used QtConcurrent::run. But I have an error like

Comment: QQmlEngine: Illegal attempt to connect to GISInventory(0xb43b07e0) that is in a different thread than the QML engine QQmlApplicationEngine(0xa260e590.

Comment: @Kevinyudo You should add a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)